# How to write below trigger on Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity

A xyz company wants to add Opportunity owner as an Opportunity Team Member on create of Opportunity .How to write Trigger?

```
trigger XyzcompOpp on Opportunity(after insert){
     list<OppTeamMember> listOTM = new <OppTeamMember>();
       for(Opportunity opp:trigger.new){
         OppTeamMember OTM = new OppTeamMember();
         OTM.TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Operation Executive';
         OTM.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
         OTM.Userid = opp.OwnerId;
         listOTM.add(OTM);
     insert OTM;         

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have created so far as the community is to help with specific issues rather than write code for you. Please see [ask]

Comment: If you simply google your question you will find suitable answer for you on first page.This time i'm doing that for you.see this link: [Trigger to add Opportunity owner in Opportunity team](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2014/05/trigger-to-add-opportunity-owner-in.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trigger createOppTeamMember on Opportunity (After Insert) {

    List<OppTeamMember> otmList = new List<OppTeamMember>(); // Initialize List

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert) {  // Check whether after insert

        for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){  
            OppTeamMember otm = new OppTeamMember();  //Initialize OppTeamMember Instance
            otm.TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Operation Executive';
            otm.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
            otm.Userid = opp.OwnerId;
            otmList.add(otm);  // Add OTM Record to OTMList
    }

    if(otmList != null && otmList.size() > 0) {
        insert otmList;   // Insert OTMList
    }
}
```

This code snippet may help to you.